# Connect a Mac thunderbolt monitor to a DELL computer running on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, multi-monitor, macintosh, xrandr, monitors

I want to have a dual screen, with the screen of my laptop + the Mac thunderbolt monitor.

- I connect the Mac thunderbolt monitor on the DisplayPort of my DELL Latitude E7440 running on Arch Linux/Manjaro
- I boot the laptop
- Nothing happens, if I run `xrandr`, it is not detected

I am totally unfamiliar with the Mac world, is what I am looking for even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been some time since I last looked into this, but if I remember correctly, even though Thunderbolt is compatible with DisplayPort, for whatever smart apple reason you can't connect your computer to the Mac monitor using a DisplayPort, it has to be Thunderbolt. And even if you had Thunderbolt on your laptop it's not guaranteed to work if it's not an macbook. Mac has really nice displays, it's such a shame that they made them so difficult to re-use.